# Chi-Squared Test Returning Infinity

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I fitted some data to a Poisson distribution, the data is as follows:

```
observed <- c(290, 630, 873, 853, 618, 310, 138, 54, 21, 9, 4)
estimated_prob_mass <- c(0.064, 0.176, 0.242, 0.222, 0.152, 0.084, 0.038, 0.015, 0.005, 0.002, 0.000)
```

Visually, the scaled distribution fits the data really well.
I used the ChiSq goodness of fit test to check the data and got the following result:

```
chisq.test(observed, p=estimated_prob_mass)

#Warning message in chisq.test(observed, p = estimated_prob_mass):
#"Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect"

#Chi-squared test for given probabilities

#data:  observed
#X-squared = Inf, df = 10, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Why would I get an infinite ChiSq value and a near zero p-value in this case?

Comment: Also if one of the probabilities you provide is 0 and the observed count is not 0 then of course you're going to reject.  Clearly that's an impossible probability vector for that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provided an estimated probability of 0 for one of the cells.  If you get an non-zero value for that cell then the test *will* reject because you got an impossible result with your probabilities.  Changing the probability vector so that the last probability is .001 and then normalizing the rest of the vector gives a more sensible result.

```
> observed <- c(290, 630, 873, 853, 618, 310, 138, 54, 21, 9, 4)
> estimated_prob_mass <- c(0.064, 0.176, 0.242, 0.222, 0.152, 0.084, 0.038, 0.015, 0.005, 0.002, 0.000)
> e <- estimated_prob_mass
> e[11] <- .001
> e <- e/sum(e) 
> 
> # Let's compare the probabilities provided versus the new ones
> estimated_prob_mass
 [1] 0.064 0.176 0.242 0.222 0.152 0.084 0.038 0.015 0.005 0.002 0.000
> round(e, 3)
 [1] 0.064 0.176 0.242 0.222 0.152 0.084 0.038 0.015 0.005 0.002 0.001
> 
> chisq.test(observed, p = e)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed
X-squared = 17.748, df = 10, p-value = 0.05936

Warning message:
In chisq.test(observed, p = e) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The main take-away is that your probability vector is either completely accurate in which case you absolutely 100% should reject the null - or it doesn't actually make sense. And if you think it should make sense and aren't understanding the result you got then you should rethink your test and consult with a statistician.  Playing around ever so slightly with the probability vector can shift the results between rejecting the null with impunity to not rejecting it in the slightest.  So I urge you to consult a statistician if this doesn't make sense.